# asp.net display values under one another in item template of gridview

Tags: html, asp.net, gridview, itemtemplate

I want the values in the cell generated from an item template to be displayed below one another in a list, rather than horizontally. [How text should look in cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4dJd.png)

```
<asp:GridView ID="dgv" runat="server">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="true"  ItemStyle-Wrap="true" ItemStyle-Width="50px">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%# Eval("Name") + Environment.NewLine + Eval("Age")+ Environment.NewLine + Eval("lang")+ Environment.NewLine + Eval("Town")%>

                </ItemTemplate>


                    </asp:TemplateField>                
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: That is how a `table` works... If you do not want that then don't use a GridView, but a Repeater.

Comment: Please post a code instead of a picture, and please clarify more what is your actual question/problem.

Comment: Hi. The text in the cell currently displays horizontally. I want it to appear as a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got what I wanted by placing a html table within the item template

```
<asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="true"  ItemStyle-Wrap="true" ItemStyle-Width="50px">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%--<%# Eval("Name") + " " + Eval("Age")+ " " + Eval("lang")+ " " + Eval("Town")%>--%>
                    <table style="width: 100%;">
                        <tr>
                            <td><%# Eval("Name")%></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><%# Eval("Age")%></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><%# Eval("lang")%></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><%# Eval("Town")%></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: If there is a better way of accomplishing this please let me know